# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toString(Z)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lokhttp3/Cookie; or its super classe

Tags: java, android, react-native, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using retrofit (2.7.2) and OkHttp version (4.4.0) in an Android project and I'm facing a crash on a request.

Dependencies:

```
kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2")
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2'     
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.7.2'

implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:4.4.0")
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0"
```

Crash:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   toString(Z)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lokhttp3/Cookie; or its super
>   classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.Cookie' appears in
>   /data/app/com.package-1/base.apk:classes3.dex)
>           at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.saveFromResponse(JavaNetCookieJar.java:45)
>           at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.saveFromResponse(ReactCookieJarContainer.java:36)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpHeaders.receiveHeaders(HttpHeaders.kt:207)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:85)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:74)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: latest version of okhttp3 is 4.4.1. change from 4.4.0 to 4.4.1. refer this https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.squareup.okhttp3

Comment: @JosePraveen updated okhttp version to 4.4.1 still getting same crash

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're pulling in an old version of okhttp-urlconnection, and it is incompatible with the current version of the OkHttp core library.

You can fix by adding an explicit dependency on okhttp-urlconnection:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1")
```

Or by adopting OkHttp’s new BOM for versions:

```
dependencies {
   implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.4.1"))
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")              // No version!
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection") // No version!
}
```

Comment: Adding `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1")` after flipper stuff in app/build.gradle worked for me :) Not sure position is relevant though

Comment: I tried first solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I used following **okhttp3 versions**  and woked fine for me...

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1'
```

Comment: I'm getting `The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used.` Is the package outdated?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that build.gradle file hase a same version for belowed dependencies and if you have this below version and getting above error than change version for them and your issue has been solved.:

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'

Change the version with below :

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that this error was showing up after ejecting from Expo in React Native.

The solution was to go to add the following to `android/app/build.gradle` (inside dependencies):

```
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.2.1"
```

They would look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
   
    // you can insert it here
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.2.1"
   
}
```

(Note: Check the versions in the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection)